# Library or code to Denoise Gaussian?

Tags: c#, .net, filter, gaussian

is there any library or code to Denoise Gaussian in .NET?

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is called a "convolution" operation with a particular type of kernel, so your search keywords might expand to convolution kernel.

Here are some links you might want to look at:

http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/features/convolution_filters.html

http://www.centerspace.net/examples/nmath/visual-basic/core/convolution-example.php

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/edge_detection.aspx

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur